# How can I launch a debug session in VSCode with multiple go files?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have two `.go` files in the `main` package.
I can run them with command `go run main.go plugin.go`.
I can also debug them with dlv `dlv debug main.go plugin.go`.

But I don't know how to debug them in VSCode, since the `program` key in `launch.json` can take only one go file as value.

This is my `launch.json` file

```json
{
        "name": "player",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "auto",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/playerserver/main.go",
        "args": ["playerserver.conf.json"]
}
```

Comment: Is it not an option to place the two files in one directory and use "${fileDirname}"?
Otherwise, how about configure a tasks.json that builds as you want and use launch/exec to exec the binary built with the preTask?

Comment: @Hana It's not very convenient to use "${fileDirname}", because the main.go file must be focused when start debugging. I think make a task to build them first is a better way, thanks a lot.

Comment: If the files are in playerserver, you can say "${workspaceFolder}/playerserver". Of course, if the folder contains other go files, that won't work. On the other hand, vscode-go extension unlikely works nicely when a directory contains multiple unrelated go files.

Answer (score 2):

Set `param` attribute points to  main package directory.

```
{
  "name": "player",
  "type": "go",
  "request": "launch",
  "mode": "auto",
  "program": "playerserver",
}
```

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1229#issuecomment-473731132

Comment: Should be `program` instead of `param` at the begining of your first sentence, right?